# Heroku pg:pull not possible due to failed authentication

Tags: postgresql, heroku

after hours of searching through Google I couldn't find a working solution to my problem.

I am using Heroku with Postgres the very first time and want to download a database backup and store it locally. I followed the instructions from here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup but I fail when importing the backup into my local db.

I did `heroku pg:backups:download --app appname` and received the file on my desktop. Now when doing `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump` I have to enter a password but I don't know which password I have to enter here. I already tried to set the username + password as variable but I am always ending up with a failed authentification. I also tried `heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL localdb --app appname` but the story is the same as above.

Can anyone please clarify how I can do this?

Comment: If you cannot connect to your own local database, then it doesn't matter what you want to do once connected.  Heroku has nothing to do with this.  Debug the local problem locally before worrying about Heroku.  There are thousands of posts on that topic.

Comment: To be entirely clear, that command connects to PostgreSQL running on your machine. Did you create a role named `myuser`? Did you assign a password for that role? Well, that's what you should use.

Comment: The user + password from the database credentials in heroku are listed in my local database which is shown in PGAdmin. I assigned a password and did SET PGUSER=myusername and tried the pg:pull again but same failed authentication. I am not sure which password or username is required here.